# Can we create a conscious agent by having two units: one rational and the other conscious?

Tags: ai-design, intelligent-agent, artificial-consciousness

Suppose we create two units (or programs) that run in parallel and we label them as a cognitive unit and the conscious cognitive unit.

A human has two units analogously. A rational analyzer and not so rational analyzer. (Is there any third thing?)

In my opinion, consciousness is an extra layer of decision making. This resembles the way metaheuristics work. We have a set of rules for decision making and we analyze them and tune those rules dynamically.

Global search algorithms mimic conscious behavior whereas the local search algorithms work as a rational mind.

So, is it possible to create a conscious agent by having two units as I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jürgen Schmidthuber has a similar concept of consciousness, maybe check out [this article](https://www.inverse.com/article/25521-juergen-schmidhuber-ai-consciousness):

> I would like to claim we had little, rudimentary, conscious learning systems for at least 25 years. Back then, already, I proposed rather general learning systems consisting of two modules.

There you also have one module that is occupied with decision making. The other module's job is to create a model of the world.

Of course, a philosopher will tell you that we have no idea what consciousness is or "what it feels like to be ai with two units".